# The analog of Krusader

Tags: filemanager, krusader

I'm using Krusader as a file manager, however it sometimes works too slow and that's why I'm looking for another one which is lighter and quicker. I like the rich functionality Krusader has and I'd like another one has it also.

Comment: Have looked at [Nautilus](http://projects.gnome.org/nautilus/)?

Comment: @Mitch, you are confusing a file manager (like Total Commander in Windows) with "file shell" (like Explorer in Windows). I don't need a file shell or explorer, I need a file manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try GNOME Commander

> GNOME Commander is a "two-pane" graphical file manager for the GNOME
>   desktop environment. GNOME Commander aims to fulfill the demands of
>   more advanced users who like to focus on file management, their work
>   through special applications and running smart commands.

To install Gnome Commander, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-commander
```

<sup>Source:Nongnu</sup>

Comment: it's pretty fast but its functionality is pretty poor compared to Krusader.